# How to make a python class able to add or multiply, with digit ahead?

Tags: python

I know there's a way to make a class compatible with these math operators with digit behind:

```
class Sth:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 1
    def __add__(self, digit):
        self.val += digit
        return self
```

Then code like `sth = Sth() * 2.8` is legal.

But how to make code like `sth = 2.8 * Sth()` legal?

(I'm doing it because there're plenty of digit-ahead operation in the third party functions I use. And i want to pass instance of my own to them.)

Comment: May be by implementing `__radd__`?

Comment: Note that your implementation of `__add__()` is radically different than a standard number - it *changes the number being added*, rather than simply returning a new number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `r` version of the double-under methods to reverse the operands

```
class Sth:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 1
    def __add__(self, digit):
        self.val += digit
        return self
    def __radd__(self, digit):
        return self.__add__(digit)
```

This will support

```
sth = Sth() + 2.8  # __add__
sth = 2.8 + Sth()  # __radd__
```

You can do the same thing for `__mul__` and `__rmul__` though pay attention to if your class is supposed to allow those operators to be commutative, otherwise make sure each implementation does the right thing in those cases.

Comment: Will be good to add [`__iadd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) and [`__imul__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__imul__) to cover all possible operations.